# Rabbitmq Virtual Host count limit and effect?

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange, rabbitmqctl

Are there any limit of RabbitMq - "Virtual Host" count?

If a virtual host have too many queue that effect on performance?

---

**Case:**

X-Virtual Host has 1500 queue. (3 GB load)

Y-Virtual Host has 20 queue. (10 Mb load)

**Question**

There will be any read and write performance difference between X-Virtual and Y-Virtual?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Spring. I suggest to ask question on RabbitMQ mailing list: https://groups.google.com/g/rabbitmq-users